# java enums - not compiling when used in other java file

Tags: java, enums, enumeration

I am trying to work with Java enums, but the code is not compiling.
I am getting the following error throughout the code.

> Class, interface, or enum expected

**Error**

vm@vm:~/Documents/Oops/DesignPatterns/CommandPattern$ javac Kitchen.java

```
Kitchen.java:1: '.' expected
import HomeApplianceAction;
                      ^
Kitchen.java:1: ';' expected
import HomeApplianceAction;
                           ^
Kitchen.java:3: class, interface, or enum expected
class Kitchen{
      ^
Kitchen.java:5: class, interface, or enum expected
    private Door_Enum kitchen_door;
            ^
Kitchen.java:6: class, interface, or enum expected
    private Fan_Enum exhaust_fan;
            ^
Kitchen.java:8: class, interface, or enum expected
    Kitchen(){
    ^
Kitchen.java:10: class, interface, or enum expected
        this.kitchen_door = Door_Enum.DOOR_SHUT;
        ^
Kitchen.java:11: class, interface, or enum expected
        this.exhaust_fan = Fan_Enum.FAN_SWITCHED_OFF;
        ^
Kitchen.java:12: class, interface, or enum expected
    }
    ^
Kitchen.java:14: class, interface, or enum expected
    public void setKitchenLights(Light_Enum kitchen_light){
```

How do I fix this error message?

Here is the code snippet :

```
public interface HomeApplianceAction{
}

enum Light_Enum implements HomeApplianceAction{
    LIGHTS_ON,
    LIGHTS_OFF,
    LIGHTS_DIM;
}

enum Door_Enum implements HomeApplianceAction{
    DOOR_OPEN,
    DOOR_SHUT;
}

enum TV_Enum implements HomeApplianceAction{
    TV_POWERED_ON,
    TV_POWERED_OFF,
    TV_STANDBY;
}

enum Computer_Enum implements HomeApplianceAction{
    COMP_POWERED_ON,
    COMP_POWERED_OFF,
    COMP_STANDBY,
    COMP_SLEEP,
    COMP_HIBERNATE;
}

enum Fan_ENUM implements HomeApplianceAction{
    FAN_SWITCHED_OFF,
    FAN_LOW,
    FAN_MEDIUM,
    FAN_HIGH;
}
```

The above code is placed in HomeApplianceAction.java file and is compiling successfully.
Now i want to use these enums in Kitchen.java file as follows :

```
import HomeApplianceAction;

class Kitchen{
    private Light_Enum kitchen_light;
    private Door_Enum kitchen_door;
    private Fan_Enum exhaust_fan;

    Kitchen(){
        this.kitchen_light = Light_Enum.LIGHTS_OFF;
        this.kitchen_door = Door_Enum.DOOR_SHUT;
        this.exhaust_fan = Fan_Enum.FAN_SWITCHED_OFF;
    }

    public void setKitchenLights(Light_Enum kitchen_light){
        this.kitchen_light = kitchen_light;
    }

    public void setKitchenDoor(Door_Enum kitchen_door){
        this.kitchen_door = kitchen_door;
    }

    public void setKitchenExhaustFan(Fan_Enum exhaust_fan){
        this.exhaust_fan = exhaust_fan;
    }

    public void execute(HomeApplianceAction action){
        if(action instanceof Light_Enum){
            setKitchenLights(action);
        }
        else if(action instanceof Door_Enum){
            setKitchenDoor(action);
        }
        else if(action instanceof Fan_Enum){
            setKitchenExhaustFan(action);
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Invalid action performed on Kitchen Appliance");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Show the error message.

Comment: Are you using any packages? If not, I strongly suggest you start doing so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have one file with multiple enums and an public interface in it. The files ".java" are called compilation units. And per compilation unit there can only be one public class, interface or enum.

You can either create spearate compilation units per enum or implement the enum within the interface and access it like:

```
HomeApplianceAction.Computer_Enum.COMP_HIBERNATE
```

Otherwise your enums are only visible from within the interface.

Comment: i created a separe .java file per enum and name is as <enum name>.java, yet same error

Comment: Thanks, It did help. placed the enums in separate .java files , and now compiling successfully. Some case-sensitive issues were left behind.

Answer (score 0):

You have several class, interface or enum in same file, which is not a best practice.

Split them into different file, ie:

in HomeApplianceAction.java:

```
public interface HomeApplianceAction{

}
```

in LightEnum.java

```
public enum LightEnum implements HomeApplianceAction{
    LIGHTS_ON,
    LIGHTS_OFF,
    LIGHTS_DIM;
}
```

Note that I write LightEnum instead of Light_Enum which follows the naming convention of java code. Note also the public modifier which allow you to use this enum in classes in other package.

You should consider declaring package for these classes and enums, and maybe you need to add import statements to be able to use them from another class like follow:

```
import LightEnum;
```

or

```
import <yourpackage>.LightEnum;
```